# Can't overwrite application variable in Sencha Touch application

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch application I am trying to set a global variable for.
**EDIT:** More clarification, I need to be able to access this global variable across all views.

I set the variable on the application to it's default value, then overwrite it during a launch. However, it's not being overwritten.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'hd',
    isAuth: 'false',
    launch: function() {
       hd.app.isAuth = 'true';
       Ext.Msg.alert(hd.app.isAuth); //This always returns 'false'
    }
});
```

I'm not getting any console errors and I cannot find anyone who is having a similar issue. I'm obviously doing it wrong. Can anyone show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `app` should not be present here. This code snippet alerts `true`:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'hd',
    isAuth: 'false',
    launch: function() {
       hd.isAuth = 'true';
       Ext.Msg.alert(hd.isAuth); // will return true as I have tested
    }
});
```

Good luck.

Edited: This should change `hd.app.isAuth` to your desire value

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'hd',
    isAuth: 'false',
    setIsAuth: function(value){
        this.isAuth = value;
    },
    launch: function() {
       hd.app.setIsAuth('true');
       Ext.Msg.alert(hd.app.isAuth);
    }
});
```

Comment: From documentation I read, `app` is required when setting global application variables. For example, if I alert `hd.app.isAuth`, it will alert whatever value I placed on `isAuth`. On an actual view, alerting `hd.app.isAuth` will alert that value still. However, alerting `hd.isAuth` returns 'undefined'. Your example is just setting a local variable, not overwriting the global which, unfortunately, I need.

Comment: I have just modified a little bit, just to create a setter function and call it. I am not sure but I guess there would be a problem with `scope` when use `hd.app.isAuth = 'true'` directly

Comment: That works in the local file, but the global variable isn't being carried into other views. Do you have any idea why this would be and what I might do to get it's value to be persistent across the entire application?

Comment: Indeed this does work, but it is flakey. I've also been working with someone on the official Sencha forums. It seems that this does set the variable, but the new value is only available in callbacks, listeners, etc. If you try to use said variable in a `config`, it fails. It doesn't seem like there is a good way to do this. Fortunately enough, we've come up with a way around it using some AJAX requests and a little PHP session handling. Since this answer is the most correct, I'm accepting it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below

```
Ext.application({
name: 'hd',
launch: function() {
   this.isAuth = 'true';
   Ext.Msg.alert(hd.isAuth); //This returns 'true'
   this.isAuth = 'false';
   Ext.Msg.alert(hd.isAuth);//This returns 'false';
}});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works within `launch`, but I need to be able to set a variable at the application level, that I can manipulate at any point, and have it's value available across all views of the application. Unfortunately, this does not do it.

Comment: Yes. You can set this any point with code hd.isAuth = true or false